# Installing GNU compilers on PureDarwin/Darwin?

Tags: homebrew, macports, gcc, darwin

I hope this is not off-topic, because there is no better place to ask this sort of questions on SO/SE. I have Downloaded and ran PureDarwin on QEMU using instructions [here](https://github.com/PureDarwin/PD-17.4-Beta):

Now I want to know if there are any package managers? Can I install HomeBrew preferably here for example or even MacPorts? If none possible how can I install GNU C/C++/Fortran compilers (GCC/g++/gfortran) here? or if it is not a possibility is there any compiler on this operating system at all? My goal is eventually to provide some Open Source developers who don't have macs with an alternative to test their software or maybe create macOS compatible binaries/packages if possible. Thanks for your support in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Your link is broken to the instructions.

FYI, the point of macOS is, to a large degree, the fact that it IS a walled garden. Having control over the entire hardware and software stack lets Apple provide a seamless, polished service and products at a premium cost.

As far as Homebrew goes, as a maintainer, I have zero optimism that it will work at all, unless the Linux version can be coerced to get installed and/or run, then maybe it *could* work (no promises) but will likely require a lot of time compiling things. Normal Homebrew (on macOS) checks for Xcode CLT and other very macOS specific stuff that won't be present in Pure Darwin. I think Homebrew on Linux will also fail because it looks for Linux headers, etc.

No matter what, this is an unsupported configuration for Homebrew and I'm 99% sure it won't work, but would be curious to learn where it fails.

I would assume/guess PureDarwin has some sort of package manager, or a package manager planned? Maybe?

Comment: updated the [link](https://github.com/PureDarwin/PD-17.4-Beta). apologies.

Comment: Thanks for the great explanations. I doubt if the PureDarwin has any  Linux bits in it though it might be PSIX compatible. I am also not aware of any package manager for the OS so far. I did some Googling there seemed to be some result for HomeBrew + PureDarwing, hence dare to ask a question here.

Comment: Also, to further elaborate on "macOS compatible binaries"... macOS dynamically links everything by default. Even though GCC/GFortran provide some flags to statically link e.g. libgfortran and other compiler/system libraries, some seem to always get dynamically linked no mater what you try. In addition, everything on macOS dynamically links libSystem.B.dylib so unless PureDarwin provides an ABI compatible lib at  /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1252.250.1) you're probably out of luck.

Comment: @Foad: "did some Googling there seemed to be some result for HomeBrew + PureDarwin"

I could be mistaken, you can always try installing it... trying it will probably take less time than asking on SO. Then you can see what the error is and if it looks fixable base your SO question on that.